# No such label 'Label_05C0' within the scope of the goto statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, goto

How do I fix the error?

> Error 23  No such label 'Label_05C0' within the scope of the goto statement   H:\calismalarim\v2\Version 2\ro.ascx.cs 582 17  Version 2

```
if (this.PriceID == "")
{
    this.ddlSelectedPrices.Visible = false;
    this.lnkClosePrices.Visible = false;
    this.lblClosePrices.Visible = false;
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    table2.Columns.Add("PriceID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    table2.Columns.Add("PriceName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    table2.Columns.Add("Count", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
    int num3 = 1;
    while (str != "")
    {
        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = str + " and " + this.method_6(Conversions.ToString(num3));
    Label_0547:
        if (ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Count > 0)
        {
            table2.Rows.Add(new object[] { num3, this.method_5(Conversions.ToString(num3)), ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Count });
        }
        num3++;
        if (num3 <= 12)
        {
            continue;
        }
        this.dlPrices.DataSource = table2;
        this.dlPrices.DataBind();
        if (this.dlPrices.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            this.divPrices.Visible = true;
            this.dlPrices.Visible = true;
            this.lblPrices.Visible = true;
        }
        return;
    Label_05C0:
        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = this.method_6(Conversions.ToString(num3));
        goto Label_0547;
        int zz21z1a = 0;
    }
    goto Label_05C0;
    int zzz1f = 0;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion: refactor and get rid of your goto's!

Comment: Been so long since I've seen one, I forgot what they do!

Comment: Go goto! Some of the worst code I've seen in a while. Hungarian notation galore, `goto`, magic values, over-use of `this`, very likely reinvented wheel `Conversions.ToString(int)`... ah... the bliss of looking at it!

Comment: Just imagine the fun you could have at code review. You could invent an entie class of profanities.

Answer (score 3):

The label is in the scope of the `while` loop, but you try to call it *outside* of the loop.

You can't do that.

Either ensure that your labels are in the [same lexical scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/13940fs2.aspx) as your gotos, or change your code - functions are good.

Answer (score 1):

This can be made to work if you modify the code at the IL level. Eg compile it with a fake goto statement, then edit the code in DNSPY and modify the goto. You can do all sorts of weird and wonderful things this way.

Not that it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Label_05C0:
            ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = this.method_6(Conversions.ToString(num3));
            goto Label_0547;
            int zz21z1a = 0;
        }
        goto Label_05C0;
        int zzz1f = 0;
```

the label is in side the while loop so it's only exists within the scope of the while statement. You are trying to jump back in there...

Using goto is rarely a good idea.
Mixing block structured code and goto is just a bad idea altogether.

Ps how are you expecting those int zzz... lines to get called, and what in world were you expecting them to do?

Are you sure goto was a good choice?

Comment: Based on the name of the label, as well as the variable names, it looks like he's trying to compile code that came from a decompiler.